# plotting datetime object in matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have an array of datetime objects that is the following

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 8, 14, 565000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 8, 35, 330000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 8, 43, 358000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 8, 52, 808000)]
```

I then tried converting the array to matplotlib suitable objects using `dates = plt.dates.date2num(dates)`

Then I tried to plot it against some values using `ax1.plot_date(dates, datac)`

but received errors as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 278, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 349, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 461, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1103, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 957, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 957, in <listcomp>
    tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 905, in iter_ticks
    for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 905, in <listcomp>
    for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._formatter(x, pos)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 412, in __call__
    return self.strftime(dt, self.fmt)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 450, in strftime
    s1 = time.strftime(fmt, (year,) + timetuple[1:])
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Supplying more complete code would help. When I guess at what you're doing I don't get any errors.

Comment: Just plot the datetime object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dates = plt.dates.date2num(dates)
```

is not appropriate as you would have used the following command

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

So here plt does not contain date2num function. So you would have to use

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
```

and `dates =date2num(dates)`.
I think this will work fine